# Why are the functions being called in my angular html bindings receiving null values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating a simple web app that represents something like a trip planner. Just offers some simple itinerary options from a list of locations in a DB I made. My `feed` page is supposed to display pictures of each `attraction`, and each `attraction` is a clickable card that will lead you to another page with some more info on that `attraction`.

```
// 
// init app
var tripperApp = angular.module('tripperApp', ["ui.router", 'ionic', 'LocalStorageModule']);

//
// setup routing
tripperApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/splash");

  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('splash', {
      url: "/splash",
      templateUrl: "partials/splash.html",
      controller: "splashCtrl"
    })
    .state("login", {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "partials/login.html",
        controller: "loginCtrl"
    })
    .state("signup", {
      url: "/signup",
      templateUrl: "partials/signup.html",
      controller: "signupCtrl"
    })
    .state("reset-password", {
      url: "/reset-password",
      templateUrl: "partials/reset-password.html",
      controller: "resetPasswordCtrl" 
    })
    .state("set-password", {
      url: "/set-password/:user_id/:password_reset_hash",
      templateUrl: "partials/set-password.html",
      controller: "resetPasswordCtrl" 
    })
    .state("feed", {
      url: "/feed",
      templateUrl: "partials/feed.html",
      controller: "feedCtrl"
    })
    .state("wishlist", {
      url: "/wishlist",
      templateUrl: "partials/feed.html",
      controller: "wishlistCtrl"
    })
    .state("specificwishlist", {
      url: "/wishlist/:user_id",
      templateUrl: "partials/feed.html",
      controller: "wishlistCtrl"
    })
    .state("share", {
      url: "/share",
      templateUrl: "partials/share.html",
      controller: "shareCtrl"
    })
    .state("attraction", {
      url: "/attraction/:attraction_id",
      templateUrl: "partials/attraction.html",
      controller: "attractionCtrl"
    });
});
```

This is my `app.js` file where I initialize all my routings and controllers. I think I am literally having problems with everything (I have a backend and everything in Nodejs, but that isn't working right because all of the values it receives is null - more on that later...).

The main problem I am seeing is that nearly all the data I am receiving is null. Nothing is really loading right - but I *know* that I have a proper connection to my DB. Because there are some places where I can see the correct results. Let me explain:

This is my `services/feed.js` file (I don't think it's very important):

```
// 
// feed service: used to get setup filters and then query for a feed using those filters
tripperApp.factory("feedService", ["$rootScope", "api", function($rootScope, api) {
  var feedService = {};

  api.get("filters").success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $rootScope.filters = data; 
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // @TODO - gracefully handle error
  });

  feedService.runSearch = function($rootScope, session, callback) {
    // add on more results
    api.post("search", {
      "start": $rootScope.currentSpot
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // copy results into array
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $rootScope.results.push(data[i]);
      }
      $rootScope.currentSpot += data.length; 

      // call callback
      callback(true); // success!
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      callback(false); // error!
    });
  };

  feedService.getWishlist = function($rootScope, session, callback) {
    // get all results
    api.post("wishlist", {
      "attraction_ids": session.picks
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // copy results into array
      $rootScope.results = data; 

      callback(true); // success!
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      callback(false); // error!
    });
  };

  // column-related functions
  $rootScope.columns = function() {
    var columns = 1; 
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

    if (windowWidth > 1300) {
      columns = 5;
    } else if (windowWidth > 1100) {
      columns = 4; 
    } else if (windowWidth > 640) {
      columns = 3;
    } else if (windowWidth > 300) {
      columns = 2;
    } 

    var rv = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
      rv.push(i);
    }
    return rv; 
  }

  $rootScope.getColumn = function(data, columnNumber) {
    var columns = $rootScope.columns().length; 
    var rv = [];
    for (var i = columnNumber; i < data.length; i += columns) {
      rv.push(data[i]);
    }
    return rv; 
  }

  $rootScope.columnClasses = function() {
    var columns = $rootScope.columns().length; 

    return {
      "col-33": (columns == 3),
      "col-25": (columns == 4),
      "col-20": (columns == 5),
      "col-50": (columns == 2)
    };
  }

  // generate thumbnail of a url
  $rootScope.thumb = function(filename) {
    return filename + ".thumb.jpeg";
  }

  return feedService; 
}]);
```

This is my controller (`controller/feed.js`) file:

```
// 
// feed controller
tripperApp.controller("feedCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, session, feedService, $ionicScrollDelegate) {
  // setup feed page (only once)
  if (typeof($rootScope.feed) == "undefined") {
    // first time loading - setup scope
    $rootScope.feed = {
      results: [],
      currentSpot: 0
    }
  } 

  // auto scroll down (if appropriate)
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    if (typeof($rootScope.feed.lastScrollPosition) != "undefined") {
      $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('feedScroll').scrollTo(0, $rootScope.feed.lastScrollPosition, false);
    }
  }, 0);

  // tell feed template that this is NOT for a wish
  $scope.wishlist = false; 

  // don't display share button on feed
  $scope.displayShare = function() {
    return false; 
  }

  // query and display results
  $scope.loadResults = function() { 
    feedService.runSearch($rootScope.feed, session, function(success) {
      if (!success) { 
        // @TODO - handle error

      }
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
    });
  }

  // whether an attraction is picked
  $scope.attractionIsPicked = function(attraction_id) {
    return session.picks.indexOf(attraction_id) != -1;
  };

  // when a result is picked/unpicked
  $scope.resultPicked = function(result) {
    var attraction_id = result.id;
    console.log(result);
    console.log(attraction_id);
    if (session.picks.indexOf(attraction_id) == -1) {
      // not yet picked, so lets pick it
      session.pickPlace(attraction_id);
    } else {
      // its picked, so lets unpick it
      session.unpickPlace(attraction_id);
    }
  }

  $rootScope.clickedResult = undefined;
  $scope.resultClicked = function(result) {
    $rootScope.clickedResult = result; 
    console.log("result: \n");
    console.log(result);
    $rootScope.feed.lastScrollPosition = 
      $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('feedScroll').getScrollPosition().top;
  }
});
```

There are a couple of functions I am specifically having problems with:

`resultPicked()` in `controller/feed.js` and `thumb()` in `services/feed.js`. I am getting null values for both of these.

My `partial/feed.html` file is as such:

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-positive" align-title="center">
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="button ion-navicon-round button-light" ng-click="toggleLeftMenu(); " style="font-size: 22px"></button>
        </div>
        <h1 class="title" ng-show="wishlist==false">New York Attractions</h1>
        <h1 class="title" ng-show="wishlist==true">
            <span ng-show="feed.user.name == 'Your'">Your</span>
            <span ng-show="feed.user.name != 'Your'">{{feed.user.name}}'s</span>
            Wish List
        </h1>
        <div class="buttons" ng-show="displayShare()">
            <button class="button ion-android-share button-light" style="font-size: 22px" ng-click="sharePage();"></button>
        </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="padding feed-page" delegate-handle="feedScroll">
        <ion-list>
            <!-- display results in columns -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col" ng-class="columnClasses()" ng-repeat="column in columns()" >
                    <div class="card" ng-repeat="result in getColumn(feed.results, column)" ng-show="feed.results.length > 0">
                        <div class="item item-image">
                            <a>
                                <img ng-src="{{thumb(result.src)}}" ui-sref="attraction({attraction_id: result.id})" ng-click="resultClicked(result)">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item item-bottom-sect">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-75 col-wrap">
                                    <a ui-sref="attraction({attraction_id: result.id})" ng-click="resultClicked(result)" class="item-title">{{result.title}}</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-25 right col-wrap">
                                    <span ng-click="resultPicked(result)">
                                        <span class="ion-heart heart heart-selected" ng-show="attractionIsPicked(result.id)" class="heart-selected"></span>
                                        <span class="ion-heart heart" ng-show="!attractionIsPicked(result.id)"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ion-list>
        <ion-infinite-scroll
            ng-if="!resultsLoaded"
            on-infinite="loadResults()" 
            distance="10%">
        </ion-infinite-scroll>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Now, in my feed, there are two called to resultClicked() and one to resultPicked(). `resultClicked(result)` will return results just fine - but `resultPicked(results)` will always gets a  null value! Also, `thumb(result.src)` always gets a null value. I have absolutely ZERO idea what - this is just things I'm confirming from `console.log`s. Is there anything glaringly wrong with the code?

Edit:

Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6D9u.jpg) displaying what I am talking about. The cards are all "broken links" because the value im getting back is null (undefined) as shown in console. The "results" are also null, as shown in the console, when called from resultPicked(), but not from resultClicked().

Comment: Your description and console does not make sense. Result should be object(result.id), but in console I see array with 24 items. Also if result is null or undefined, `var attraction_id = result.id` should throw error. I dont see any error in your console.

Comment: @bigless sorry for the late response man. The array with 24 items is coming from the `console.log` output in `clickedResult`, which is the last function `feed.js`. It is the not the result of object(result.id). But  I agree with your second statement... yet it is undefined...